# Sprite Kit Animation: Atlas Error

Tags: animation, sprite-kit, atlas

I dragged a texture atlas into my project. The pictures are named correctly ("heliani_1-9")
The animation is running smooth, except for 3 frames, which are displayed as big red cross on a white ground. (See screenshot enclosed)

[image]

What is wrong with my code?

Cheers

```
#import "MRMPlayer.h"

@implementation MRMPlayer

-(instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    {

        [self setupAnimations];

        [self runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction animateWithTextures:self.runFrames timePerFrame:0.5 resize:YES restore:NO]] withKey:@"heli"];

        self.name = playerName;
    }
    return self;
}


-(void) setupAnimations{
    self.runFrames = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    SKTextureAtlas *heliAtlas = [SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed:@"heli"];

    for (int i = 0; i < [heliAtlas.textureNames count]; i++) {
        NSString *tempName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"heliani_%d",i];
        SKTexture *tempTexture = [heliAtlas textureNamed:tempName];
        if(tempTexture) {
            [self.runFrames addObject:tempTexture];
        }
    }
}


@end
```

Comment: The big red X means that the images were not found in your atlas. Confirm that you have all the images, you think you have, for your animation in your atlas.

Comment: I know, I checked it several times. They are there and named correctly. I even cleaned my project several times, tried it with renamed ones, I don't get rid of it.

http://s7.directupload.net/images/140507/rxv7kwtk.png

Comment: I spy with my big eye that image 6 has a naming inconsistency :) Not sure if that could be causing all your issues but certainly contributing.

Comment: Thank you, how can I overlook smth like that? :D Unfortunatelly the error still appears :(

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with your posted code. The error could be in your actual images or something else entirely. I suggest you give Texture Packer a try. It creates texture atlases and even does animations. You can download a free copy here http://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker

Comment: Cheers m8, I will try that one :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the product menu, and you will see the `Clean` option.

Now, hold down the `option` button on your keyboard and the text should change to `Clean build folder...`

Choose that option, and it will additionally delete the derivative data folder that caches alot of things including the texture atlas, and I've found to cause problems like you have described. If you rename files in the atlas, thats typically when I have experienced this issue  myself.

I don't like that this option is something you kind of have to work for, would be nice to have this second option there WITHOUT having to hold down the option key.

If this doesn't solve the problem, you truly have a naming problem imo.

**Note**
You can also delete the derivative data folders from the Organizer window.

Comment: Thank you, but the error is still there. I will create new PNGs on my own and try it again. I need one upvote in order to upvote comments (I have 14 at the moment) Plz give me one upvote, and I will upvote your answer. Cheers

Comment: I'd check your filenames for any differences from what your code is looking for. Are the frames for the animation, the only ones in the atlas ? You are using the `count` property of the atlas in a loop to determine frame numbers. So, if there are other textures in that atlas besides your animation, that could cause the same problem as well.

Comment: Ok, just noticed that you start your loop at 0, and in your atlas, there is no `heliani_0`. That could result in a big red x.  You do a test to see if the texture exists, maybe throw a `NSLog` in there so you can see if that test is false if `0` is the index.

Comment: Thank you, god sir! Of course, that was the issue. I needed the i start from 1 instead of 0. You are the best! Thank you so much!